# How to specify which WindowGroup should appear on visionOS app launch?

Tags: swift, swiftui, visionos, vision-pro, swiftui-windowgroup

I'm writing a visionOS application using SwiftUI. The app utilises multiple `WindowGroup`s.
I'm struggling with window management, especially in terms of window dismissal and app relaunch.

Here's a demo code presenting the problem:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct demoApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            FirstView()
        }

        WindowGroup(id: "second") {
            SecondView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First window group")
            Button("Open second window group") {
                openWindow(id: "second")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Second window group")
    }
}
```

I'm proceeding with the following actions:

1. The app launches with the first `WindowGroup`.
2. Click the button calling `\.openWindow` and opening the second `WindowGroup`.
3. Click the native 'close' button at the bottom of the first window.
4. Click the native 'close' button at the bottom of the second window. Now all of the groups are closed.
5. Relaunch the app by clicking the app icon from the Home menu.

The app launches showing the second `WindowGroup` as it was the last one closed. I want the app to open the first `WindowGroup` (the root one in my case) instead.

Is there any way of specifying which window group of the scene should be opened in such situation?

I haven't found any information in the documentation about detecting which `WindowGroup` is opened at the moment, also haven't managed to come up with a solution using `\.scenePhase`.

Comment: Look into: [`handlesExternalEvents(matching:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scene/handlesexternalevents(matching:)/) and [`handlesExternalEvents(preferring:allowing:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/handlesexternalevents(preferring:allowing:)/)

Comment: How could `\.scenePhase` help here?

Comment: @soundflix thanks, I'll look into `handlesExternalEvents`, hope it'll help me out. About `\.scenePhase` I was thinking about a workaround detecting phase change from `inactive` to `active` on app relaunch and somehow detecting which window group is being presented

Comment: @erotsppa not really. I've realized that dismissing a window by clicking the bottom control doesn't kill the window, but only minimizes it and keeps its state. I ended up redesigning the flow of my app's navigation, so I'm able to call `openWindow` opening the first window by clicking a button in the second view